# Loopback and Firebase

Tags: mongodb, firebase, datasource, loopbackjs

I'm having problems with the authentication settings of the loopback with firebase in datasource.

I have a **"post" module**, and I already tested with the **"post" method** in the loopback explorer and it worked, the loopback is sending the data to firebase, but when I enable the rules for only "Authenticated Users" to be allowed to post, I can login and **set the token**, but when I try to execute the "post" method in the Post module I get the 401 message from unauthenticated user.

To see if I had something wrong I tested with the datasource `db in memory` and `mongodb` and it worked.

I did use the connectors: `loopback-connector-realtime-database and loopback-connector-firestore`.

Comment: So your rules are for Firestore or for RTDB? They have completely different rules. Can you specify how are your rules and which of those connectors are you using?

Comment: are you using firestore or firebase-auth?